# Adding a Serial (cck field) to the Page Title

Tags: entities, 7

I don't really know PHP or how to modify the Drupal API so it would probably have to be a solution in the Drupal interface or rather simple programming.

Is it possible to have a Serial cck field automatically combine with the page/node title? Example, Title: Update Example Task. Serial (job number): 225 -- Automatically combine to make the page/node title: 225 Update Example Task  -- So it can be referenced as a autocomplete term with either the Serial field or the Title

Thanks for any input!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout [auto_nodetitle](https://drupal.org/project/auto_nodetitle), you could add the serial field as a token to the node title automatically.

The rest should then just fall into place.

Comment: Excellent Solution, exactly what I was looking to do, thanks!